# How can i loop through a list of dates of string data type to pass each date to an sqlcommand to get the rows from a table into datagridview

Tags: c#

This is a function to pass a parameter month which has a value between 1 to 12 in string. I get two dates which is the start of the month and the start of the next month. I calculate the difference between those two dates (difference) and calculate the difference between the dates in my table (difference2) and compare each difference2 to difference so that i select only the dates that are in the same month. Then i want to display the rows which have the dates i saved in an array and fill that in DataTable object to put in DataGridView control. Im stuck on the filling the DataTable object.

```
    public object monthlyReport(string month)
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        string year = date.ToString("yyyy");
        string firstDate, secondDate;
        if (month == "12")
        {
            firstDate = "01/" + month + "/" + year;
            secondDate = "01/01/" + (Int32.Parse(year) + 1).ToString();
        }
        else if (month == "10" || month == "11")
        {
            firstDate = "01/" + month + "/" + year;
            secondDate = "01/" + (Int32.Parse(month) + 1).ToString() + "/" + year;
        }
        else if (month == "09")
        {
            firstDate = "01/" + month + "/" + year;
            secondDate = "01/10/" + year;
        }
        else
        {
            firstDate = "01/" + month + "/" + year;
            secondDate = "01/0" + (Int32.Parse(month) + 1).ToString() + "/" + year;
        }
        //MessageBox.Show(firstDate);
        //MessageBox.Show(secondDate);
        con.Open();
        /*SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Rooms where Date between '" + firstDate + "' and '" + secondDate + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;*/
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(Date) from Rooms", con);
        int count = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select Date from Rooms", con);
        string[] dates = new string[count];
        int index = 0;
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            dates[index] = dr.GetString(0);
            index++;
        }
        List<string> newDates = new List<string>();
        foreach (string dateItem in dates)
        {
            TimeSpan difference = Convert.ToDateTime(secondDate) - Convert.ToDateTime(firstDate);
            TimeSpan difference2 = Convert.ToDateTime(secondDate) - Convert.ToDateTime(dateItem);
            if (difference2.TotalDays < difference.TotalDays)
                newDates.Add(dateItem);
        }
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (string dateItem2 in newDates)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Rooms where Date = '" + Convert.ToDateTime(dateItem2).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'", con);
            //da.TableMappings.Add(dt);
            //SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select * from Rooms where Date = '" + Convert.ToDateTime(dateItem2).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'", con);
        }
        
        con.Close();
        return dt; 
    }
```

Comment: Dates are not strings, strings are not dates.  Why not pass (and store Dates) to the database?   Then you can pass a date using a SQL Parameters for any queries.   Note that Visual Studio would seem to have nothing to do with this post.

Comment: I declared the Date column in my Room table as vchar(50) because i had problems before using date datatype

Comment: Well, you've succeeded in making that massively more hard work than it needed to be!

Comment: Working with dates as strings will lead to problems down the line and code as complicated as you show. Databases generally have several Date and Time data types. C# has DateTime. If you work in that domain, most things just work (excluding time zones and Daylight Saving Time, both of which can be a PITA)

Comment: @caius, not just a lot more work, massively more bug-prone

Comment: add datas in SqlDataAdapter before you fill Datable.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you just used proper date time types like you ought to, you can download the rows for a month using this simple code:

```
DataTable dt;

var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN @d AND EOMONTH(@d)";
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, "CONNECTION STRING")) {
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@d", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = new DateTime(2021, 6, 1);
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```

It's properly parameterized too, so [this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vtech+hack&t=h_&ia=web) won't happen to you..

If the complaint is that it misses off dates on the last day that have a time, you need to appreciate that dates with times are like numbers with decimals, midnight being `.0` for any given number - asking a db for `WHERE x BETWEEN 1.0 AND 31.0` will naturally omit 31.5 (noon on the 31st day). In such a case, use `WHERE x >= @d AND x < @d2` and add another parameter that you calculate yourself or `x < DATEADD(D, 1, EOMONTH(@d))` if you want the DB to calc the end of the month from the start date provided. This way you're effectively saying "less than 32" for the day which does capture 31.5